# CvRect* in C++ to Rectangle[] in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm developing an app in C# and I need to use a method defined in a C++ dll. That method returns a `CvRect*` and I want to know how can I, in some way, do a wrapping for use it as a `Rectangle[]`. I'm using Emgu Cv in C#.

The method signature in the .h  looks like these:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT 
CvRect* MyClass::MyMethod(char* path, int* lenght);
```

where `lenght`is the number of `CvRect`returned.

The C# code:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "MyMethod")]
    public static extern IntPtr MyMethod(string path, ref int lenght);

int lenght = 0;
IntPtr h_result = MyMethod(path, ref lenght);

CvRect[] result= new CvRect[lenght];

var sizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CvRect));
for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
{
    IntPtr p = new IntPtr((h_result.ToInt32() + i * sizeInBytes));

    result[i] = (CvRect)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(CvRect));
}
```

Comment: Please provide the method signature. How do you know the size of the returned array BTW?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski the method signature in the .h  looks like these: 
extern "C" DLLEXPORT 
CvRect* MyClass::MyMethod(char* path, int* lenght);                                      where lenght is the number of CvRect returned.

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the method signature so it's easier to read. Please also include the definition for `CvRect`.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline the method signature is already included in my original post. CvRect is an struct provided by OpenCv that basically represent a rectangle with properties like width, height and x and y coordinates of the upper left corner. [link](http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/roswiki/docs/diamondback/api/opencv2/html/c++/structCvRect.html)

Comment: I don't think you will be able to wrap it directly; you will still need to get the results in unmanaged space (i.e. as an `IntPtr`) then transfer it to managed space. Is this what you're having trouble with?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline yes, I need to convert the IntPtr to an array of CvRect (an struct that I created in C# to emulate the CvRect of the OpenCV)... I'm having problems with that, please help me.

Comment: Ok so your code looks fine. Does it work? If so, just create an array of `Rectangle`s and assign them the same way: `Rectangle[] rect = new Rectangle[lenght];` ... `rect[i] = new Rectangle(result[i].x, result[i].y, result[i].width, result[i].height);` Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline the code works but it shows a warning or something like that:
*Additional Information: A call to PInvoke function (MyMethod) has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.* Despite that, I give continue and it works, but wondered how to remove warning...

Comment: Your calling convention is most likely incorrect. Change your C# function's attribute to: `[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "MyMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline I was working in VS 2010 with the OpenCV 2.2 and now, I migrated the same code to VS 2012 with the version 2.4.6 of the OpenCV. I'm having this Error with or without the CallingConvention that you suggest me: *Unable to load DLL 'MyDLL.dll': Can not find the specified module. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)* Why it is that?

Comment: "Can not find the specified module" should be a dead giveaway. It can't find `MyDLL.dll` in the same folder as the executable. Copy it over from the old location and you should be good to go.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline `MyDLL.dll` is already in the same folder of the executable, that's why I don't know what else to do...

Comment: Are you *absolutely certain* of that? The error message says it can't find it. After compiling your project from Visual Studio, go to the folder the executable is in and run it from there. Verify that the same folder has the DLL file in question. If the file is indeed there and it says it still can't find it, you'll have to create a new question; this discussion is already off-topic.